# Which is better for installed applications: /usr/bin or user's home directory?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

It's not entirely clear to me whether it would be better to install a GUI application in `/usr/bin` or my home directory. I've read through [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-speakingunix11/) and [this one](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), but it doesn't really talk about philosophy of how to use these different directories. Should commands should be treated differently from GUI applications?

Answer (score 11):

The `/usr/bin` is the primary directory of executable commands on the system.

The `/usr/local`:

- Used by the system administrator when installing software
  locally.
- It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system
  software is updated.
- It may be used for programs and data that are shareable amongst a
  group of hosts, but not found in `/usr`.

Locally installed software must be placed within `/usr/local` rather than `/usr` unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software in /usr.

More [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY).

Answer (score 7):

There is no particular reason to make a difference between GUI and CLI commands.

`/usr/bin` belongs to the operating system so, even while nothing prevents you, as root, to do it, you shouldn't put anything here. This directory is for people distributing software integrated with the OS and properly handling/avoiding name conflicts.

`/usr/local/bin` is a common directory for locally built software. If you can write here, you can just use this directory.

`/opt/<name>/bin` is for software not belonging to the OS. It is a good location for shared software.

Your home directory belongs to you so you are free to put anything you like anywhere under it but it is not the best location if other people need to run your program.

Comment: So is the only difference between /usr/local/bin and /opt/foo/bin where/how the software was installed? So as a rule, any software I manually install should go in the the former and anything installed from a package manager will end up in the later?

EDIT: It appears so. [link](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE14)

Comment: Yes. Note that locally built software might also go to /opt/local/bin. This avoid an issue with /usr/local that much be writable while /usr might be mounted read-only.

Answer (score 4):

Do not install anything manually in `/usr/bin`. The whole of `/usr`, as well as `/bin`, `/lib` and `/sbin`, are reserved for software provided by your distribution. There is an exception: `/usr/local`, which is intended for programs installed by the system administrator and is not touched by package managers (except for creating a few directories). (That's on Linux, other unix variants may have package managers that install software under `/usr/local`.)

Between `/usr/local` and a place in your home directory, the choice is yours. If you want a program to be available to all users, put it in `/usr/local`. If you want it to be available only for you, install it in your home directory.

Whether the program has a GUI or not is irrelevant.

Comment: `/opt` is also sometimes used for local installations, though the division between `/usr/local` and `/opt` is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If it makes sense (or is required) for the user to be able replace the binaries of the application then it must be installed in the user's home directory. Otherwise it can be installed in a public, read-only directory such as `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

For global use you can install it to /usr/bin but nobody recommends that.

For using some application as a specific user (it should be more secure, when running it as 1 user) install it to home directory of specific user.